# How can I store hexadecimals inside an array? C++ MFC

Tags: c++, sockets, mfc, hex

I have to use an array of hexadecimals because I'm doing a program to communicate with a video server controller and he just understands messages in hexadecimal. I can connect the video controller with my server, but when I try to send messages using the send() function, passing an array of unsigned char that contains my information in hexadecimal, it doesn't work.

This is how I am using the array. I don't know if it is correct.

```
 void sendMessage()
        {
               int retorno;
           CString TextRetorno; 
               unsigned char HEX_bufferMessage[12]; // declaration

            // store info
                HEX_bufferMessage[0] = 0xF0;
                HEX_bufferMessage[1] = 0x15;
                HEX_bufferMessage[2] = 0x31;
                HEX_bufferMessage[3] = 0x02;
                HEX_bufferMessage[4] = 0x03; 
                HEX_bufferMessage[5] = 0x00;
                HEX_bufferMessage[6] = 0x00; 
                HEX_bufferMessage[7] = 0xD1; 
                HEX_bufferMessage[8] = 0xD1; 
                HEX_bufferMessage[9] = 0x00;
                HEX_bufferMessage[10] = 0x00;
                HEX_bufferMessage[11] = 0xF7;

        retorno = send(sckSloMo, (const char*) HEX_bufferMessage, sizeof(HEX_bufferMessage), 0); 

                TextRetorno.Format("%d", retorno);
                AfxMessageBox(TextRetorno); // value = 12

                if (retorno == SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    AfxMessageBox("Error Send!! =[ ");
                    return;
                }



            return;

            }
```

Comment: Not to be mean but you need to go back and learn some basics. Hexadecimal is a way of 'displaying' a numeric value. It's not a type of variable. I think your problem will become clearer once you understand the basics. Good luck.

Comment: Maybe you just need this: `send(sckSloMo, "F0153102030000D1D10000F7", 11, ...`. It depends on what you mean by "the video server controller just understands messages in hexadecimal".

Comment: Michael, I said that because the developer manual that I received says that the messages are in hexadecimals, even those that my server receives from the controller.

With this message, I'm trying to draw a rectangle on the video controller screen. I've tried to do like you said, passing to send() function a string with the message. But it doesn't draw the rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

Pop quiz.  What's the difference between:

```
int n = 0x0F;
```

and:

```
int n = 15;
```

If you said, "nothing,"  you're correct.

When assigning integral values, specifying `0x`, `00` for octal, or nothing for decimal makes no difference in what is actually stored.  This is a convenience for you, the programmer only.  These are integral variables we're talking about -- they store numeric data only.  They don't store or care about radix.  In fact, you might be surprised to learn that when you assigned a numeric value to an integral variable, what is actually stored isn't decimal or hexadecimal or even octal -- it's binary.

Since you're storing these values as `unsigned char`, and `char` (`unsigned` or otherwise) is really just an integral type, then what you're doing is fine:

```
HEX_bufferMessage[0] = 0xF0;
HEX_bufferMessage[1] = 0x15;
HEX_bufferMessage[2] = 0x31;
```

but your question makes no sense:

> Anyone knows if using an array of unsigned char is the right way to
>   store hexadecimals??